# Change suite bar logo on site level

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016, site, suitebar

Is it possible to change the suite bar text and URL only on site level?

Change at `sharepoint/test` site but don't change at `sharepoint/` site collection.

I tried this, but this make changes for all sites:

```
$web = Get-SPWebApplication "http://test
$web.SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl ="http://google.com"
$web.SuiteNavBrandingLogoTitle = "Test"
$web.SuiteNavBrandingLogoUrl = "logo URL"
$web.SuiteNavBrandingText ="Dev 
$web.Update()
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge you cannot do modify Suite Bar at site level using Powershell. You can edit the master page and add JavaScript there. Follow the answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72178/modifications-to-the-suite-bar-are-only-applied-to-the-top-level-site-in-the-sit/72262).

Answer (score 1):

The cmdlets that you used is used to set the Suite Bar branding for a web application, all site collections which is hosted in the web application will be affected. More information, you can refer to [that](https://github.com/powershell/sharepointdsc/wiki/SPWebAppSuiteBar).

For sites, there is no property for suitbar. About [SPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite?view=sharepoint-server).

For your requirement, I suggest you use JavaScript code to achieve it.